# Archive message based on which inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm in Outlook 2016. I have three different Inboxes in Outlook, each for a different address. I would like to set up a keyboard shortcut that will mark the current message as read, and transfer it to the Archive folder associated with the current Inbox/email address. I tried a Quick Step, but for that you point it to a particular Archive folder, and then that's the one it will transfer to, regardless which Inbox you're actually running the Quick Step from.

How can I get Outlook to do move it to a different folder based on the current Inbox the message is in?

Comment: How did you create the Quick Step? Which Archive folder did you move the email to? You need to create three different Quick Steps to move the emails to different Archive folders for each account. Give a specific name to each Quick Step to help you distinguish these Quick Steps.

Comment: I thought about that, but I sometimes forget which keystroke belongs to which Inbox, and it's a mess trying to re-find those misplaced emails & re-archive them. I'd really like a solution where I consistently use the same keystroke, and offload to the computer the mental work of checking which Archive to use.